# How would i have a UILabel act as a Button when clicked and open a blank email?

Tags: objective-c

I have built a directory of sorts.  There are 133 people.  I have three labels.  "Name", "Position", and "email".  How would i make the email label act as a button to open a blank email with the address from the label?  Th problem I'm running into is the label is dynamic, and I'm having trouble setting it up.  Im a beginner so any help would be appreciated!

this is the .h file-

```
@interface PersonDetailControllerViewController : UIViewController

@property(weak) IBOutlet UILabel *name;
@property(weak) IBOutlet UILabel *position;
@property(weak) IBOutlet UILabel *email;

@property(strong) Person *person;

@end
```

this is the .m file-

```
#import "PersonDetailControllerViewController.h"

@interface PersonDetailControllerViewController ()

@end

@implementation PersonDetailControllerViewController

@synthesize name, position, email, person;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

self.name.text = self.person.name;
self.position.text = self.person.position;
self.email.text = self.person.email;

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@end
```

Comment: One solution is to use a `UIButton` instead of a `UILabel`.

Comment: can a button be dynamic?

Comment: Can yoy be more clear as to the situtation.  Exactly how is your data structure set up?  What dose a "directory of sorts" mean?  That in particular would be very helpful to help you solve this.

Comment: Yes, button's contain a `UILabel`, so they can be dymanic

Comment: ok, its basically a contact list.  Its for teachers at a school i go to.

Comment: Ok, but how are you storing that list.  Is it in a dictionary, array, etc.?

Comment: sorry, i just upload the code above, i misunderstood!  thanks

Comment: Ok, that helps.  Can you also explain how you want it to show up on the view.  1 button that changes every x seconds? 5 buttons, one for each teacher? etc?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40077/discussion-between-andrew-and-user2918086)

Answer (score 2):

A `UIButton` contains a property called `titleLabel` which is actually a `UILabel`, so you don't need to use a `UILabel` you can simply use a `UIButton`. What you'll do is after you add the button, is use the method `- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)title forState:(UIControlState)state`. That will set the `titleLabel` property to whatever you specify in the `NSString` that you pass it.

Edit: If you're dead set on using a `UILabel` for this, you could do the following:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
label.text = @"My Label";
label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(alert)];
[label addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Then in your method, do whatever you want it do do. In my case `alert` is defined as:

```
- (void)alert
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, basically what you need to do is create another `viewController`, that will be a generic page that will be populated based on the teacher selecated.  When the user taps a row in the tableView, you should transtition to the detailView.  There are many ways to do this transtition (progmatically, Storyboard segues, etc.), but here is an example:

```
TeacherDetailViewController *controller = [TeacherDetailViewController alloc] init];
controller.teacher = array[indexPath.row];
```

Where teacher is a property (`@property(nonatomic, strong) Person *person;`) on that new class `TeacherDetailViewController`.  By setting the teacher property, and then transtitioning to that new class, the new class will get the information from the `person` object that was selected.

In the `TeacherDetailViewController` class, you would set up the view including the email button, and in `viewDidLoad`, you would have:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    teacherName.text = self.person.name;
```

}

Then I would have a button in that class that said email the teacher, and that button should be linked to an action method, which could look something like this:

```
-(void)sendEmail {
 MFMailComposeViewController *mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mailViewController setToRecipients:self.teacher.email];

[mailViewController setSubject:@"Subject Goes Here."];
[mailViewController setMessageBody:@"Your message goes here." isHTML:NO];

[self presentModalViewController:mailViewController animated:YES];
```

}